# Polygon decomposition into minimum star-shaped polygons

Tags: computational-geometry, partitions, decomposition

As the title suggests, I'm trying to implement an algorithm to decompose a polygon into the minimum number of star-shaped polygons. I've been searching for quite some time but I can't find any algorithms or even anything theoretical to study on this problem online. The closest I found is decomposition to the minimum number of convex polygons.

Any suggestions as to how I should approach the problem?

I've tried to think about it by myself but the combinations seem too many and I don't want to get into writing an algorithm while my main problem is still unsolved.

Comment: Seems an open problem. [This paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0214056) introduces an algorithm for decomposition without Steiner point.

Comment: @xskxzr Yes, Keil's algorithm is just what I need. I come across his name everywhere but I was hoping I wouldn't have to pay for an article.

Comment: @xskxzr Do you know if the minimum star-shape number with Steiner points would be the same as without Steiner points?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know.